# c++ reduce the dimensions of a matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, dimensions

I got the following problem: I got a 9x9 matrix which I want to reduce to an 5x5 matrix. I want to this by cancelling the last 3 rows and columns and by cancelling the 3rd row and column.
My code looks like this. But it does not work properly.

```
for (int A=0;A<6;A++)
  for (int B=0;B<6;B++)
      if ((A!=2) || (B!=2))
          disshess5x5(A,B) = disshessian(A,B);
```

Comment: What doesn't work properly? How doesn't it work?

Comment: I get from this                                                                             [0.0887628, -0.0612372, 0.122474, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 -0.0612372, 0.0887628, 0.122474, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0.122474, 0.122474, -0.094949, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0.15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.15, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.15, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.15, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.15, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.15]

Comment: this matrix                                                                                    [0.0887628, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 -0.0612372, 0.0887628, 0.122474, 0, 0,
 0.122474, 0.122474, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0.15, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.15

Comment: How are both matrices declared ?

Comment: To skip a row and a column the test should use `&&`, not `||`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always wise to be explicit in what you are trying to implement, so it should be easily readable.

In this example you should define which rows and columns you want to skip:

```
const bool rowToSkip[9] = { false, false, true, false, false, false, true, true, true, true };
const bool colToSkip[9] {...};
```

As already answered you should also define source to target index mapping:

```
const int tgtRow[9] = {0,1,2,-1,3,4}; // and in the same way tgtCol
```

With such consts you will get clean loops, easy to spot any errors:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
 if(!rowToSkip[i])
     for (int j = 0; j < 9; ++j)
       if(!colToSkip[j])
         tgtMatrix[tgtRow[i]][tgtCol[j]] = srcMatrix[i][j];
```

---

**[UPDATE]**

It can be also done in a little faster way by just defining target->source indexes:

```
const int srcRow[5] = {0,1,3,4,5};
const int srcCol[5] = {0,1,3,4,5};

for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) 
     for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
         tgtMatrix[i][j] = srcMatrix[srcRow[i]][srcCol[j]];
```

BTW - your range `[0,6)` is of `length == 6` - you should use `[0,5)` range to meet `5x5` matrix

Comment: This worked! But I changed srcRow[5] to {0,1,3,4,5} (same for the columns) in order to skip the 3rd element

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the index for the skipped row and col

```
for (int A=0;A<6;A++)
  for (int B=0;B<6;B++)
      if ((A!=2) && (B!=2))
          disshess5x5(A-(A>2),B-(B>2)) = disshessian(A,B);
```

for example when `A` is `4` you want to write to index `3` instead and this code works because `A>2` is `true` and will be converted to a `1` implicitly when doing math (`false` instead is converted to `0`, thus leaving indexes `0` and `1` untouched).